# NPM install is not working on angular-cli project

Tags: angularjs, node.js

when i run this command npm install i get an error, i also try this command npm install -g angular-cli
please help me to solve it out

```
H:\Superstar\vision-front-end-dev-master>npm install
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true 
   config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  erikflowers/weather-icons resetting remote C:\Users\Arslan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-erikflowers-weather-icons-git-0c0a2917 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
```

Comment: npm install, will install whatever is in that directory's package.json file (that is, the directory you are running npm install from). 

npm install -g angular-cli, will install the angular-cli globally, so that you can run angular-cli commands (like "ng serve") from whatever project directory you're working in. Based on your question, I get the idea you may not be enitrely up on npm, package.json files, etc. 

Refer to this for basic angular-cli setup. 

https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Did you `ng init` your root folder after installing?

Comment: i face error while installing